# Using Firebase within the physical network of an organization - not on the cloud

Tags: firebase

If for security and regulatory reasons an organization can not run its core internal business processes on the cloud, is there a solution by which Firebase could still be used, for example run only within the physical network of that organization ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a pure cloud-hosted solution. There is no on-premise version available.