# Firebase Database local - VPS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vps

I am using Firebase database, and i want to migrate that to my VPS.

Is it possible? Can I download the schema and data to import in my VPS?

Thanks.

Comment: You can download your JSON at any time, either through one of the APIs or by using the backup option. But there no self-hosted version of the Firebase Database available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929499/using-firebase-within-the-physical-network-of-an-organization-not-on-the-cloud/40935211#40935211

Comment: so i cant migrate to another nosql database? is there an nosql database wich run with a local motor?